# dynamic overlay for video using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to write a program in python to be used by people with a disability while they use something as a hometrainer (or MotoMed). To do so I have to be able to show a video and write additional info/images to the screen if need be. This info is dependant on other sensors (including a Hall Effect sensor and sensors that can detect a spasm for instance).

Using the Pygame Movie feature you can update the screen frame by frame using the pygame.update() function. See: [How to load and play a video in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356439/how-to-load-and-play-a-video-in-pygame) However, I need to run other video formats (Pygame can only play MPEG-1) and am therefore playing with the[VLC python bindings](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings) to  [render a video in pygame window](https://gist.github.com/smathot/1521059).

VLC renders the video directly onto/into the pygame window. TO do so you have to provide it with the window ID:

```
player.set_xwindow(win_id)
```

Instead of rendering it on the window I need to render it on a Pygame surface such that I am able to update the screen with pygame and write other info to the screen as well. With the pygame Movie function it would be

```
movie_screen = pygame.Surface((x,y)).convert()
movie.set_display(movie_screen)
movie.play()
```

I have noticed that there is a nextframe function in the VLC bindings. Is it possible for pygame to dynamically obtain this frame and put it on a surface? I guess this will be quite slow, but I am willing to give it a shot as it is my only guess at getting a dynamic overlay for videofiles other than MPEG-1 in python/pygame.

Comment: You are asking for a method, but _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._".

Comment: Of course, I should have remembered. I have altered my question, though it is still quite open for interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question!