# Embed Pygame video in to Tkinter with control Buttons for raspberry-pi GUI

Tags: python, wxpython

I have got webcam video stream inside a wxpython GUI. can i use video capture function with wxpython button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VLC bindings and do it that way: http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/tkvlc.py;h=55314cab09948fc2b7c84f14a76c6d1a7cbba127;hb=e8d4373a7e9699f0a5a533cb0da144a037a08c2a

Comment: you need to install the vlc python bindings (and vlc) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443396/dynamic-overlay-for-video-using-python