# Displaying a video in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I followed what was done in the question in the following link ([How to load and play a video in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356439/how-to-load-and-play-a-video-in-pygame))

But what actually happens is a smaller window pops up with a black screen, video doesnt play.

Video is in .mpg

```
def game_credits():
    Creds = pygame.movie.Movie("C:\Users\itzrb_000\Documents\gameCreds.mpg")
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(Creds.get_size())
    Creds_screen = pygame.Surface(Creds.get_size()).convert()

    Creds.set_display(Creds_screen)
    Creds.play

    playing = True
    while playing:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.blit(Creds_screen, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(50)
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

For new readers, please note, that the Movie class, has been removed from pygame.

You could try the [moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) or [pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) modules. But it's not integrated to pygame.