# Which game engine to use for video in background

Tags: python, c++, video-streaming, game-engine

I'm working on an art project where images will appear on a screen according to certain rules, with a video running in the background. I thought a game engine would be best for this.

I've tried kivy, but couldn't get the video to go in the background. I don't have a graphics card, so unreal isn't an option.

Any thoughts on what would be good? I'm most comfortable with Python and C++, but open to anything.

Comment: BTW: all computers have graphics card - at least embeded. Without graphics card you couldn't display anything.

Comment: BTW: python module [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) can read video  (or camera) frame-by-frame so you can read frame and display it like any other image - if you do it in loop then you get video. And if you add another static image/text/ine/igure then you may have image/text/line/figure with video in the background.

Comment: in PyGame you read video frame-by-frame and display in loop to get video - [How to load and play a video in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356439/how-to-load-and-play-a-video-in-pygame). And then you can add static image to get video in background. But PyGame may works only with some video formats so you may have to convert video to use it with PyGame.

Comment: in [Pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can read video frame-by-frame and use it in on_draw to display as background - doc: [incorporating-video](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/media.html#incorporating-video). Maybe [Arcade](https://arcade.academy/index.html) can do the same because it is built on top of Pyglet.

Comment: it seems python's version of [processing](https://py.processing.org/)can read and [display video](https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-to-display-video-in-pythonmode/485) frame-by-frame so you can add any other element (other image, text, line, figures) to create static element with video in background.

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant external graphics card. Thanks for all the ideas! I believe PyGame's video capabilities have been discontinued, and I previously had some issues with Pyglet. Managed to fix it after your suggestion, and Pyglet seems to do the trick. Thanks!